# How can I group by specific rows and calculate the mean of each column?

Tags: r, dataframe

Basically I am trying to group my values by day and I want to calculate the mean of each station (ACO, AJM, etc) for each day, ignoring null values.

This is the head of my data frame:

```
 FECHA     HORA   ACO   AJM   ATI   BJU
01/01/2019    1  -99.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0
01/01/2019    2  -99.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0
01/01/2019    3  -99.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0
01/01/2019    4  1.5   0.1   0.9   1.0
01/01/2019    5  1.2   0.1   0.6   1.3
01/01/2019    6  1.0   0.1   1.0   1.0
```

Where "FECHA" is the day and "HORA" is the hour of each day.

I am currently trying to do it like this:

```
mdiaria2019CO <- datos2019CO %>% group_by(FECHA) %>% colMeans(datos2019CO[ , c(3:34), na.rm = T])
```

but RStudio keeps telling me "invalid 'dims'" or that there is an incorrect na.rm.

How can I group all the values by day (every 24 rows) and calculate the mean of each column for that day, ignoring the null values (-99)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `across` -

```
library(dplyr)

mdiaria2019CO  <- datos2019CO %>% 
                    group_by(FECHA) %>% 
                    summarise(across(ACO:BJU, ~mean(.[. != -99])))

#  FECHA        ACO   AJM   ATI   BJU
#  <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 01/01/2019  1.23   0.1 0.833   1.1
```

`.[. != -99]` will ignore the missing values which are represented by `-99.0`.

Answer (score 0):

We can also this as

```
library(dplyr)
mdiaria2019CO <- aggregate(.~ FECHA, datos2019CO[-2], FUN = function(x)
              mean(x[x != -99]))
```